# Flutter - prevent tap/click events from being passed through view hierarchy

Tags: flutter, onclick, onclicklistener, hierarchy, flutter-layout

I'm looking for the best way to **stop tap/click events from being propagated** up the view hierarchy. Suppose we have a simple scenario with a **TextField** decorated with a an 'X' **clear text button**.

When I click the "X" button the click **event** is propagated up to TextField's onPressed().

```
final _textEditingController = TextEditingController(text: "");

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return TextFormField(
    controller: _textEditingController,
    onTap: onEditTextTapped,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      suffixIcon: IconButton(
        onPressed: onClearTextClick,
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.clear,
          size: 20.0,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 18),
  );
}

void onEditTextTapped() {
  print('TextField tapped');
}

void onClearTextClick() {
  print('clear text clicked');
}
```

[image]

The result is:

```
flutter: clear text clicked
flutter: TextField tapped
```

I need something similar to Android's `android:clickable="true"` or Flutter's `AbsorbPointer` that would trap all click events and stop them from being passed through to the view beneath BUT only when I click 'clear text' button. Click event from `TextFormField` should still trigger `onEditTextTapped()`

Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.2, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132)

Comment: TextFormField doesn't have any parameter named 'onTap'

Comment: @Eugene Flutter version is: Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.2, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132)

Comment: Have you tried `IgnorePointer` and `AbsorbPointer` ?

Answer (score 3):

Use [pointer_interceptor](https://pub.dev/packages/pointer_interceptor) widget, especially if you target Web with complex layouts involving maps, `Stack`, `drawers`, `Positionned` widgets, etc. So in your case it would be something like:

```
import 'package:pointer_interceptor/pointer_interceptor.dart';
...
return TextFormField(
    controller: _textEditingController,
    onTap: onEditTextTapped,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      suffixIcon: PointerInterceptor(
        child: IconButton(
          onPressed: onClearTextClick,
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.clear,
            size: 20.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 18),
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

use Stack as an option :D

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      children: <Widget>[
        TextFormField(
          controller: _textEditingController,
          onTap: onEditTextTapped,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            suffixIcon: IconButton(
              onPressed: onClearTextClick,
              icon: Icon(Icons.clear, size: 20.0),
            ),
          ),
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 18),
        ),
        IconButton(
          onPressed: onClearTextClick,
          icon: Icon(Icons.clear, size: 20.0),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: As this technically works, `IconButton` in `InputDecoration` should work as well